# Facebook OAuth in Node.JS: storing the access token

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm implementing a backend which interacts with Facebook, using the OAuth API. Firstly, I exchange an authorization code for an access token:

```
var accessTokenUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/oauth/access_token';
var params = {
    code: req.body.code,
    client_id: req.body.clientId,
    client_secret: config.FACEBOOK_SECRET,
    redirect_uri: req.body.redirectUri
};
request.get({
    url: accessTokenUrl,
    qs: params,
    json: true
}, function(err, response, accessToken) {
    ...
});
```

I'll be needing that access token for feature requests to the Facebook API (requesting profile information, posting to timeline etc.), so I need to store it somewhere server-side. Can I do this just by doing this:

```
exports.access_token = access_token;
```

In other words, is exports.access_token unique for every connection with Node.JS, or is this variable shared by all clients (in which case I could absolutely not do this)?

I also use JSON web tokens, so I could also do this after requesting the token:

```
function createToken(accessToken) {
    var payload = {
        sub: accessToken,
        iat: moment().unix(),
        exp: moment().add(14, 'days').unix()
    };
    return jwt.encode(payload, config.TOKEN_SECRET);
}
```

For using the token for feature requests, I could simply do:

```
var token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
var payload = jwt.decode(token, config.TOKEN_SECRET);
var accessToken = payload.sub;
```

Or is this not advisable either? The reason I would use the JSON web tokens, is because I use Satellizer, which uses this be default.

Comment: `exports` is usually `module.exports`, which is cached and shared across the entire app, what you seem to need is sessions and/or a DB that stored users and tokens.

Comment: Would it be advisable to use the second option, using JSON web tokens? I've just tested it out and it seems to work, but I'm not sure if this is the right way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use the `passport` module with the `passport-facebook` extension?

See

- http://passportjs.org/
- https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook

I don't understand the *I also use JSON web tokens...* part, because this has nothing to do with the Access Token you'll be receiving from Facebook.

Comment: Using JSON web tokens, I can store the Facebook access token within the payload of my JSON web token, and decode it whenever I need it for a request (e.g. posting to a Facebook wall). I'm using this NodeJS in conjunction with an AngularJS app, therefor I'm using Satellizer, which uses these web tokens. But I'm not sure if this is the best way to go?

Comment: If you use Satellizer, everything seems to be already build-in regarding the Access Token / OAuth process. So why would you code that yourself?

Comment: In the Sattelizer server example (https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/blob/master/examples/server/node/server.js), the Facebook token is nowhere saved. Only the local user is saved, and I replaced it with the FB token. In my application, I'll to interaction with Facebook all the time, once I have the access token. But I'm not sure how to handle this kind of thing. The Facebook token obviously has an expiration date, so is it wise to store it somewhere altogether? Or should I request a new one on each interaction with Facebook?

Comment: You could exchange the short-lived token to a long-lived one, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending This one will be valid for 60 days

Comment: Thank you for the useful help! I've found a web topic where I can get some ideas as well: https://hackhands.com/building-instagram-clone-angularjs-satellizer-nodejs-mongodb/#/satellizer